# copying text on an Android tablet

Tags: utf

I write all of my books in an ancient DOS program Maxthink.  If I copy text into an app that saves it as a text file, which I get is garbled.  Regular alpha-numeric characters are ok; semicolons & quotation marks are not.  I have one app that allows me to save in UTF 8 & 16.  One of the UTF options does not garble the text, but leaves spaces where the puntuation is supposed to be.

Comment: I've read this twice, and still can't find the question.

Comment: The question is how to avoid the problem.  Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: I got your email and responded back.